# Help with understanding Rating Systems

Tags: statistics, recreational-mathematics

Hey guys so I'm trying to come with a rating system from 1-10 that will be determined based on how close a user is to an average value that I have. I don't have any data(other than the average value) to work with, so standard deviation is not possible. So lets say I want to give a number to a household based off of how many children they have(assume average is 2), if a house has higher than two its value will be a bit higher than 5. Is there any documentation/articles/books I could read to get a better grasp of where to look? Sorry for being a bit vague, but I don't know where the right places to look are in this matter, hope you guys can help!

Comment: when they hit your average score, should your rating be 5 or 10?

Comment: If they are right on the average they would be a 5, the more they diverge from 5 the further they are from the average(hope that helps)

Comment: There is no information is a single number. If you are talking about the number of kids in a household then being wrong by $2$ is a lot, but if you are talking about guessing the number of people in the world then being off by $1000000$ is extemely good. You need some estimate on what constitutes a reasonable deviation from your value. If you don't have any data to determine this use your head and make an educated guess.

Comment: I guess I don't have much to go on and as such will have to do with an educated guess. Thanks for your help.